# Are there any standards for markup like the one that SO site uses?

Tags: html, xhtml, formatting, markup

I will like to design/develop a formatting markup for an application that we are developing.  Is there any standard on this like what StackOverflow uses when writing each question description.

Comment: Can somebody please change the title to "Are" instead of "Is"? I cringe every time I scroll past this. I'm allergic to bad grammar. I've temporarily remedied the solution with a post-it note stuck to my screen as I type this.

Comment: @Sneakyness: There you go. :)

Comment: Sorry for that Sneakyness, ESL issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SO uses [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown).  Other interesting approaches include [Wikitext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikitext) and [BBCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode).

Answer (score 7):

There are lots and lots of [lightweight markup languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language) out there. 
[Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) and [Textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_(markup_language)) are two that I like.